# Android: Could not execute method for android:onClick- save button click error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, illegalstateexception

I've got problem with this error. I don't know why , but it stopped suddenly working. After I click the Save button it shows this message. I'm starting to be desperate. I would be grateful for any help!

```
06-23 17:18:02.918 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-23 17:18:03.088 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
06-23 17:18:03.088 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15053: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
06-23 17:18:03.088 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15057: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-23 17:18:03.199 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14952: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
06-23 17:18:03.199 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-23 17:18:03.199 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-23 17:18:04.320 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/skia: FontHost open localized file: /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml
06-23 17:18:04.680 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace I/Adreno200-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB4.04.01.02.16.028_msm8960_JB_REL_RB4.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
                                                                           Build Date: 12/06/12 Thu
                                                                           Local Branch: 
                                                                           Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb4.2
                                                                           Local Patches: NONE
                                                                           Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-23 17:18:04.750 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/libc: pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x51029e31, tls=0x53eddf00, arg=0x4005f1a8
06-23 17:18:04.750 5102-5159/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/libc: pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x51029e31
                                                                  , tls=0x53eddf00, arg=0x4005f1a8
06-23 17:18:04.770 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x53ede000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:61
06-23 17:18:04.770 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50263000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:63
06-23 17:18:04.810 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-23 17:18:05.031 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x545b7000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:66
06-23 17:18:05.031 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5029a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
06-23 17:18:05.141 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x548b5000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:70
06-23 17:18:05.141 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x502af000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:72
06-23 17:18:05.311 5102-5115/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/libc: pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40311509, tls=0x54bb2f00, arg=0x5176b400
06-23 17:18:05.311 5102-5187/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/libc: pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40311509
                                                                  , tls=0x54bb2f00, arg=0x5176b400
06-23 17:18:10.737 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ca3468)
06-23 17:18:10.777 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at jansoldat.formularkomunikace.MainActivity.SaveData(MainActivity.java:253)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-23 17:18:12.739 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: killProcess, pid=5102
06-23 17:18:12.749 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
06-23 17:18:12.769 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
06-23 17:18:12.769 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:944)
06-23 17:18:12.769 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
06-23 17:18:12.769 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
06-23 17:18:12.769 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
06-23 17:18:12.779 5102-5102/jansoldat.formularkomunikace D/Process: dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my mainactivity

```
 package jansoldat.formularkomunikace;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE = 1;

    Button buttonPridejStaniceni,button_Vyber_Fotku, button_Fotak;
    TableRow Radek_2, Radek_3, Radek_4,Radek_5,Radek_6;
    ImageView imageView_VyberFotku, imageView_Fotak;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri_vybrana;

    /*===========Databáze Prvky====================*/
          /*==========Staničení====================*/
    EditText editText1__0m,editText2__0m,editText3__0m/*,editText1__2m,editText2__2m,editText3__2m,editText1__4m,editText2__4m,editText3__4m,
             editText1__6m,editText2__6m,editText3__6m,editText1__8m,editText2__8m,editText3__8m,editText1__10m,editText2__10m,editText3__10m*/;

    /*==========Staničení Stringy============*/
    String sirka_0m,podelny_sklon_0m,pricny_sklon_0m/*,sirka_2m,podelny_sklon_2m,pricny_sklon_2m,sirka_4m,podelny_sklon_4m,pricny_sklon_4m,
           sirka_6m,podelny_sklon_6m,pricny_sklon_6m,sirka_8m,podelny_sklon_8m,pricny_sklon_8m,sirka_10m,podelny_sklon_10m,pricny_sklon_10m*/
            ,velikost_poruch,cetnost_poruch,nerovnosti_povrchu,obrazek_galerie;


    /*ChechBoxy*/
    CheckBox checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch, checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu, checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu, checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch, checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch;

    /*RADIoBUTTONY*/
    RadioButton radioButton_bez_nerovnosti, radioButton_mirne_zvlneny, radio_button_velke_nerovnosti;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonPridejStaniceni = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPridejStaniceni);

        Radek_2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_2);
        Radek_3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_3);
        Radek_4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_4);
        Radek_5 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_5);
        Radek_6 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_6);

        imageView_VyberFotku = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_VyberFotku);
        button_Vyber_Fotku = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Vyber_Fotku);

        imageView_Fotak = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_Fotak);
        button_Fotak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_fotak);

        checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch);
        checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu);
        checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu);

        checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch);
        checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch);

        radioButton_bez_nerovnosti = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton_rovny_bez_nerov);
        radioButton_mirne_zvlneny = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton_mirne_zvlneny_s_malymi_nerovnost);
        radio_button_velke_nerovnosti = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton_zvlneny_s_velkymi_nerovnostmi);

        if (!hasCamera())
        {
            button_Fotak.setEnabled(true);
        }



        /*==============Databáze prvky=============*/
          /*=================Staničení=============*/
        editText1__0m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_0m);/*******/ editText2__0m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_0m);/****/ editText3__0m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_0m);
       /* editText1__2m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_2m); editText2__2m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_2m); editText3__2m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_2m);
        editText1__4m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_4m); editText2__4m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_4m);editText3__4m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_4m);
        editText1__6m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_6m); editText2__6m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_6m); editText3__6m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_6m);
        editText1__8m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_8m); editText2__8m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_8m); editText3__8m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_8m);
        editText1__10m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1__10m); editText2__10m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2_10m); editText3__10m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3_10m);*/

        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent dbmanager = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AndroidDatabaseManager.class);
                startActivity(dbmanager);
            }
        });




    }

    int[] views = new int[]{R.id.Radek_2,R.id.Radek_3,R.id.Radek_4,R.id.Radek_5,R.id.Radek_6};//...
    int counter = 0;
    public void PridejDalsiStaniceniClicked(View v)
    {
        findViewById(views[counter]).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(counter<views.length){
            counter++;
        }

        if(counter==views.length)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.buttonPridejStaniceni).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vyčepal jsi maximální možnou velikost staničení!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    public void BezPoruchClick(View v)
    {
        if (checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch.isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(false);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(true);
        }
    }

    public void MensiPoruchyClick(View v)
    {
        if (checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu.isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(false);

        }else {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(true);



        }
    }

    public void VetsiPoruchyClick(View v)
    {
        if (checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu.isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(false);

        }else {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu).setClickable(true);



        }
    }

    public void MalaCetnostClick(View v)
    {
        if (checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch.isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(false);


        }else {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(true);


        }
    }

    public void VelkaCetnostClick(View v)
    {
        if (checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch.isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(false);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(false);


        }else {
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch).setClickable(true);
            findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch).setClickable(true);


        }
    }


    public void SaveData(View view)
    {
        sirka_0m = editText1__0m.getText().toString();
        podelny_sklon_0m = editText2__0m.getText().toString();
        pricny_sklon_0m = editText3__0m.getText().toString();

            /*===========Velikost poruch povrchu==============*/
        if (checkBox_povrch_bez_poruch.isChecked())
        {
            velikost_poruch = "Povrch bez poruch";
            cetnost_poruch = null;
        }
        if (checkBox_mensi_poruchy_povrchu.isChecked())
        {
            velikost_poruch = "Menší poruchy povrchu";
        }

        if (checkBox_vetsi_poruchy_povrchu.isChecked())
        {
            velikost_poruch = "Větší poruchy povrchu";
        }
         /*==================================================*/

        if (checkBox_mala_cetnost_poruch.isChecked()){
            cetnost_poruch = "Malá četnost poruch";
        }
        if (checkBox_velka_cetnost_poruch.isChecked()){
            cetnost_poruch="Velká četnost poruch";
        }

            /*============RadioButton=======================*/
        if (radioButton_bez_nerovnosti.isChecked())
        {
            nerovnosti_povrchu = "Rovný povrch bez nerovností";
        }
        if (radioButton_mirne_zvlneny.isChecked())
        {
            nerovnosti_povrchu = "Mírně zvlněný povrch s malými nerovnostmi";
        }
        if (radio_button_velke_nerovnosti.isChecked())
        {
            nerovnosti_povrchu = "Zvlněný povrch s velkými nerovnostmi";
        }

            /*=============IMAGE======================*/
        obrazek_galerie = imageUri_vybrana.getEncodedPath();



        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute("add_info", sirka_0m, podelny_sklon_0m, pricny_sklon_0m,velikost_poruch,cetnost_poruch,nerovnosti_povrchu,obrazek_galerie);

    }

    public void Vyber_fotku_clicked(View v)
    {
        openGallery();
    }
    private void openGallery()
    {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }



    public boolean hasCamera()
    {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    public void PouzijFotakClicked(View v)
    {
        Intent vyfot = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(vyfot , REQUEST_CAPTURE);
    }




    /* Výběr obrázku a vyfocení*/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView_Fotak.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri_vybrana = data.getData();
            imageView_VyberFotku.setImageURI(imageUri_vybrana);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use the XML attribute to add the listener, do it programmatically. With yourView.setOnClickListener(yourListener);

Comment: Line of interest: `NullPointerException
                                                                                at jansoldat.formularkomunikace.MainActivity.SaveData(MainActivity.java:253)`